# replacing config file with another via script

Tags: bash

I have an app that has a config file. Is there a way to replace all the text in the file with other text i have. Instead of using sed to modify the current file. Id like to just rip all the text from the file and add in my own file then save the changes, Ideally this will be run with the user signed in as the user or sudo as well so permissions should be ok.

file location: ~/Library/Application \Support/App/config_file.json

Comment: `ust rip all the text from the file and add in my own file then save the changes` Soooo just copy the file?

Comment: Or, put both files under `~/Library/Application \Support/App/` say `config_1.json` and `config_2.json`. Then simply create a symlink for `config_file.json` or whichever you want, e.g. `ln -sf ~/Library/Application \Support/App/cofig_1.json ~/Library/Application \Support/App/config_file.json`. You can simply change the link back and forth as needed. Include the `-f --force` option to enable replacing the link without it warning the link already exists.

Comment: @KamilCuk @DavidCRankin "Replacing" all the text in the file should mean "overwriting" the file; `cp` or symlinks won't do that. I'm not sure that the OP is aware of the difference though.

Comment: `cp or symlinks won't do that` but it "does that", cp follows symlinks. Well, you can `cp -L` to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

cat < other_file > my-config.json

Comment: Is there a reason 2 redirections is better than `cp other_file my-config.json`?